# Django form with one too many fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to work out how to create a form for my Invoice model. It will include filling in the fields for my InvoiceLine model. This is possible via the admin interface, registering an inline object to the InvoiceAdmin model.

Any pointers on how to proceed for the same behavior on the front end?

The following are the models simplified only to include the model relationship and an arbitrary number

```
from django.db import models

class Invoice(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

class InvoiceLine(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
```

Comment: Can you show us your model structure? That Current information is not enough

Comment: Thanks I've added to model structure. The answer is to use an inlineformset_factory. I'd like to add my answer my own question.

Also I wanted to add inlineformset_factory to my tags, but the only tag available was inline_formset which does not exist in Django and could be misleading. formsets and inlineformset_factories are advanced topics in Django and adding them to the tags may help many people.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do the lines and header of invoice via javascritp and send a json to server with the data, we work this way

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inlineformset_factory. This wasn't my idea I found it on this blog post [Django's Inlineformset_factory and You](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/djangos-inlineformsetfactory-and-you/). Thanks Charles.